# Is there a Left/Right algebra? Definition confusion...

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We can define an $A$-algebra $R$ as a ring R with a map $A \to Z(R)$. Equivalently, we can be slightly more restrictive and only consider fields where we have a ring $R$ and a field $F$ and $R$ is an $F$-algebra if
$$c(xy)=(cx)y=x(cy)$$

## Question:

Is it not true that, say

$$x(cy)=(xc)y$$

since $c$ can be thought of as (or identified with if you prefer) an element of $Z(R)$? I know we have left/right modules but there doesn't (to me) seem to be an equivalent identifications for algebras. I do know that $R$ can be thought as an $F$-module. What I am thinking then is that we could equivalently write the multiplication on the right and we have made a notational choice only. Since our ring of scalars will always be commutative any left module is also a right module. Is this the idea or am I missing something?

## Related Post(s):

[Modules over an algebra: confusion in understanding "left" and "right" business](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049137/modules-over-an-algebra-confusion-in-understanding-left-and-right-business)

Comment: Yes, your idea is correct: as long as $A$ is commutative, any left $A$-module induces a right $A$-module, moreover an $A$-$A$-bimodule structure naturally, with the same action.